# Google maps full screen not showing in a special case

Tags: google-maps

I have a webpage that shows google map. It is working fine in standalone mode. Unfortunately when my other website with same domain name calls this page in an iframe, google map div doesn't show the fullscreen control button. All other action buttons are visible and no other bug I found. Below is the code:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById('map_container'),
    {
        zoom: 5,
        center: center,
        disableDefaultUI: true,
        fullscreenControl: true,   //all other controls works fine
        gestureHandling: 'greedy'
    }
);
```

EDIT: This is for desktop.

These are two jsfiddle links. One where I create a map and ohter page loads the previous one in an iframe. The full-screen button is missing the the second one.

- [Link of map having full-screen button](https://jsfiddle.net/swaroopdeval/ebxv78ot/)
- [Link of a page that loads first one in iframe](https://jsfiddle.net/swaroopdeval/j8cu47mz/)

Comment: Are you able to provide us with a self contained sample (http://sscce.org) that will demonstrate the issue?

Comment: @rafon edited the question. I added to links for demo of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The issue was with the iframe syntex. I was not using `allowfullscreen` flag. If google map js detects if it doesnt have fullscreen permission, it doesnt render fullscreen button.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe